# UIButton in UIView not getting touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, singleton

I have the following code in a viewController:

```
BubbleChatSingleton *myBubble = [BubbleChatSingleton sharedBubbleChat];
UIView *myQuestionView;
myQuestionView = [myBubble createBubbleChat];
[question_middle_view addSubview:myQuestionView];
```

The [myBubble createBubbleChat] contains the following code:

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18 + (65 * (media_count % 4)), (5 + (media_rows * 65)), 60, 60)];

UIImageView *current_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
// Get the image
documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/question_image_%@.png", [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0], [current_media objectForKey:@"id"]];
UIImage *mediaImage = [self imageByCropping:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath] toRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
[current_imageView setImage:mediaImage];
[mediaImage release];
[parentView addSubview:current_imageView];
[current_imageView release];               

UIButton *overlay_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
overlay_button.tag = [[current_media objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
overlay_button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);
[overlay_button addTarget:self action:@selector(viewMedia:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[parentView addSubview:overlay_button];
```

However the overlay_button is not receiving any of the click events.  It doesn't even look like I pressed the button at all. (ie. not visual changes us usually see with a UIButtionTypeRoundedRect)

I have double checked that no other views are transparent over top of the button, could anything else cause this?  Is the fact that I am return the button as a subview of a UIView from a singleton method matter?

Comment: What's the frame of `question_middle_view`? Might be too small.

Comment: It is scaled based on the height of the content that fills it. Sadly, it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `userInterActionEnabled` on your current_imageView and parentView.

EDIT:

I also noticed that you are adding target for `self`, which in you case is `BubbleChatSingleton`, but not the controller you are in. So the action will be triggered in `BubbleChatSingleton`. Do you have such method in there?

Comment: That did not seem to change anything. :(

Comment: @user1048121 take a look at edited answer, i've just noticed another issue.

Comment: I do have the function defined. Here is the header line:

`code`- (void)viewMedia:(UIButton*)sender;`code`

and the function:

`code`-(void)viewMedia:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Sender Tag: %d", sender.tag);
}`code`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
[overlay_button addTarget:self action:@selector(viewMedia:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

To:

```
[overlay_button addTarget:self action:@selector(viewMedia:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**UIControlEventTouchUpInside** is the proper control event for detecting UIButton touches.

Comment: I have tried both UIControlEventTouchDown and UIControlEventTouchUpInside it was originally UIControlEventTouchUpInside to begin with, I just forgot to change it back when I posted the code.